# Before upload your app to Google Play? Performance

Tags: android

Before upload your app to Google play. I know that Google recommends use OptiPNG for the icons, also you need to **include icons for all screen sizes**.

What about the code? Is needed **obfuscate the code** to make it tiny like a JS in WebDev?

Or does matter the comments and all log that you need to develop? There are some bits. **It affect the app performance**?

What things should be considered before uploading?

Comment: yes... so remove all logs, base on log someone able to hack your webservices..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 0):

> you need to include icons for all screen sizes

Not for screen sizes but for DPIs. Also, you don't need to include icons for ldpi.

> Is needed obfuscate the code to make it tiny like a JS in WebDev?

No. Java code is compiled, so unlike with JavaScript there is no improvement in performance when doing this. Obfuscation is done so that it is much harder to decompile and change your application, it does not affect preformance (actually, some deep obfuscation of compiled code makes it slower but Android's ProGuard does not do that).

> Or does matter the comments and all log that you need to develop?

Again, Java is compiled, comments are ignored and are not in the application code. Logs for development should be used only in development:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    Log.d(your debug message);
```

`BuildConfig.DEBUG` is a constant so the `if` is elided during compilation, removing the call to `Log.d` completely in release builds.